# Array items showing error in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array with some items to rotate the image view when button is clicked, now when I pass the array with getting current index it showing an error, I'm confused why I'm getting this.
My code is this:

```
- (IBAction)my:(id)sender {
NSString *cureentIndex=0;
NSArray *persons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"M_PI",@" M_PI_4",@" M_PI_2",@"M_PI*2", nil];
NSArray *person = @[@"M_PI", @"M_PI_4", @"M_PI_2"];

_imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(person[cureentIndex])

if currentIndex != persons.count-1 {
    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1
}else {
    // reset the current index back to zero
    currentIndex = 0
}
}
```

The error is here:
[image]

Comment: Be aware that `M_PI`, `M_PI_2` etc are **preprocessor macros** (via `#define`) which return `double` values rather than strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issues, please try this

```
NSInteger currentIndex = 0;
NSArray<NSNumber *> *persons = @[@(M_PI), @(M_PI_4), @(M_PI_2)];

- (IBAction)my:(id)sender {
    _imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(persons[currentIndex].doubleValue)
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % persons.count;
}
```

Comment: what is doubleValue, it is showing error on doubleValue. @vadian

Comment: `doubleValue` is s property of `NSNumber` to get the *primitive* type. I updated the answer to declare the array with a static type.

Comment: Bro, the error is removed  but the logic is not working for rotation. @vadian

Comment: Actually this is another question.

Comment: yes i know u have given my answer but if u can help me in this bro ? @vadian

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `cureentIndex` as `NSString *`, so when you say `person[cureentIndex]` the compiler thinks that `person` must be a dictionary, since you are using the `[]` access with an object. This causes the error since `person` is actually an array and it cannot be indexed with a string.

I think you meant to declare `cureentIndex` as `int`, or perhaps you meant to say `currentIndex`?

Comment: Bro when i give int currentIndex = 0 it shows error here person[cureentIndex] that passing 'id' parameter of incompatible type CGFloat (aka 'double'). @Paulw11

Comment: You have stored NSString objects in your array;  It would be simpler to use a C array of float rather than an NSArray

Comment: how to do that . @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors:

The index must be an int

```
NSString *cureentIndex=0;
```

becomes

```
int currentIndex = 0;
```

and the array must be of double not string, [CGAffineTransformMakeRotation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455666-cgaffinetransformmakerotation) requires a CGFloat that is a double

```
NSArray *person = @[@"M_PI", @"M_PI_4", @"M_PI_2"];
```

becomes

```
NSArray *person = @[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI_4], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI_2]];
```

and

```
_imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(person[cureentIndex])
```

becomes

```
_imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation([person[cureentIndex] doubleValue]);
```

Comment: There is a more convenient syntax: `@[@(M_PI), @(M_PI_4), @(M_PI_2)];`.

Comment: i have changed the code as u have given above but still it shows error here person[cureentIndex] that passing 'id' parameter of incompatible type CGFloat (aka 'double')..@Kerberos

Comment: @Raheel You have to write `person[cureentIndex].doubleValue`

Comment: this passing 'id' parameter of incompatible type CGFloat (aka 'double'). @Kerberos

Comment: What is doubleValue? it is undeclared . @vadian

Comment: what is doubleValue, it is showing error on doubleValue. @Kerberos

Comment: @Raheel, [doubleValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414031-doublevalue?language=objc)  is a property to get the double value of variable ([double](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double))

Comment: the logic is not porperly working for rotation. @Kerberos

Comment: @Raheel Which logic? With this code when you click it rotate the imageView with M_PI, if you want rotate on every click, you can move the counter out of the IBAction and increment it, when the counter is equal to the number of the array you can reset the counter.

Comment: how to set the counter with the code bro. @Kerberos

Comment: i have if condition with current index this if (currentIndex != persons.count-1) but this is not working. @Kerberos

Comment: @Raheel you can use something like this:
`_imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation([person[cureentIndex] doubleValue]);
 if (currentIndex < [person count]) {
 currentIndex++;
}
else {
  currentIndex = 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

- I don't know why you set currentIndex's property to NSString, In fact we always set the XXXindex(current/last/next) to int or NSInteger property.
- Another, the person is an array, it's key must be an int!, it's
  value could be any object.
- I fix your code to this:

  NSInteger currentIndex = 0;

  NSArray *person = @[@"M_PI", @"M_PI_4", @"M_PI_2"];

  CGFloat rotate = [person[currentIndex] floatValue];

  _imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotate);
- you will find it did't work well, the ratate will be 0! Because, the NSString's method `floatValue` or `doubleValue` can only change string(like: @"123" @"0.5") to a number, the string(like: @"M_PI") can't be change to a right number.
- I fix your code to this again:

  NSInteger currentIndex = 0;

  CGFloat mPi = M_PI;

  NSArray *person = @[@(mPi), @(mPi / 4.0), @(mPi / 2.0)];

  CGFloat rotate = [person[currentIndex] floatValue];

  _imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotate);
- The Code works well! This is because M_PI is A **Macro**, if you
  write code @"M_PI", the system can't recognize its value 3.1415926. So
  your must write M_PI instead of @"M_PI".

*In fact, this problem's core is you need a number, so your array must include some numbers! Or some string just like number! :)*